# find if a string ends with semicolon or a word

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex to determine if a string ends with semicolon or "BEGIN" or "THEN". Also before BEGIN and THEN words, there must be a white space or line break character.

```
if(strLineText.matches(";|THEN|BEGIN$"))
```

This works for THEN and BEGIN but not for semicolon. And also with this regex I could not determine if THEN and BEGIN are exact words.

Comment: Try `(;|THEN|BEGIN)$`

Comment: @Tushar - `\\b` means word boundary. The delimited is not supposed to be new-line character always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put them inside a group.

```
if(strLineText.matches("(?s).*(?:;|\\bTHEN|\\bBEGIN)$"))
```

or

```
if(strLineText.matches("(?s).*(?:;|\\sTHEN|\\sBEGIN)$"))
```

Comment: *Also before BEGIN and THEN words, there must be a white space or line break character.* :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar: singleline mode forces `.` to match newlines. `\s` matches linebreaks even without this modifier.

Comment: @rdonuk: You actually can use [`if (Pattern.compile(";|\\bTHEN|\\bBEGIN$").matcher(s).find())`](http://ideone.com/oNg6ST). You just needed a `matcher.find()` and the word boundary. Also, note than  a linebreak *is* a whitespace character. Thus, `\\s` can be used to match a space and newlines.

Comment: @stribizhev - I guess I need to re-read what some characters mean in regex. Thanks :)

Comment: @rdonuk it's just a noncaturing group. `(?:regex)` non-capturing group. `(regex)` capturing group. We must use the capturing group only if it's necessary. Here non-cap group would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple lookahead for the same.

```
^(?=.*(?:;|[ \\n]THEN|[ \\n]BEGIN)$).*$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regex.

You can use `.endsWith()` method too.

```
String str = "hey;";

if(str.endsWith(";"))
 System.out.println("Ends with a  ;");
```

---

```
public static boolean endsWithWord(String str, String word)
{
  return str.endsWith(word);
}
System.out.println(endsWithWord("hey;", ";"));
System.out.println(endsWithWord("umm BEGIN", "BEGIN"));
System.out.println(endsWithWord("umm THEN", "THEN"));
```